# Getting "ClientHello too short" on SSL server

Tags: c#, ssl, chilkat

I'm using the Chilkat C# library for SSL server. When the client connects to my server, I get the message "ClientHello too short" error message. I have another server with which this client works with no errors. Following is a copy of the error message I get.

```
ChilkatLog:
  AcceptNextConnection:
    DllDate: Dec 12 2012
    UnlockPrefix: Anything for 30-day trial
    Username: BUSTER-VAIO:Buster
    Architecture: Little Endian; 32-bit
    Language: .NET 4.0
    VerboseLogging: 0
    fd: 0x490
    objectId: 1
    hcCurDate: Thu, 24 Jan 2013 11:05:24 -0700
    hcExpire: 3/2013
    listenPort: 50600
    AcceptSslConnection:
      maxWaitMs: 20000
      m_idleTimeoutMs: 10000
      readIncomingTls_clientHello:
        readTlsRecord:
          Received SSL 2.0 ClientHello.
          recLen: 52
          2-byte record header...
          nToRead: 49
          fullRecord: 0103 0100 1B00 0000 1002 0080 0400 8000
0003 0000 0600 0008 0000 1400 000B 0000
0E00 0011 F0BF 3491 D043 9A04 9FB3 155C
642C F945
          cipherListLen: 27
          sessionIdLen: 0
          challengeLen: 16
          cipherKind: 128
          key_len: 512
          cipherKind: 128
          key_len: 1024
          cipherKind: 3
          key_len: 0
          cipherKind: 6
          key_len: 0
          cipherKind: 8
          key_len: 0
          cipherKind: 20
          key_len: 0
          cipherKind: 11
          key_len: 0
          cipherKind: 14
          key_len: 0
          cipherKind: 17
          key_len: 0
          buildClientHello:
            majorVersion: 3
            minorVersion: 1
            numRandomBytes: 16
            sessionIdSize: 0
            numCipherSuites: 0
            numCompressionMethods: 1
          --buildClientHello
        --readTlsRecord
        processTlsRecord:
          processHandshake:
            handshakeMessageType: ClientHello
            handshakeMessageLen: 0x17
            processHandshakeMessage:
              MessageType: ClientHello
              ClientHello:
                MajorVersion: 3
                MinorVersion: 1
                ClientHello too short (1).
              --ClientHello
            --processHandshakeMessage
          --processHandshake
        --processTlsRecord
      --readIncomingTls_clientHello
      Failed to read incoming handshake messages. (10)
      Server handshake failed.
    --AcceptSslConnection
    Failed.
  --AcceptNextConnection
--ChilkatLog
```

This is my first experience working with the Chilkat library.  Does anyone have a suggestion as to where I should start? I can't change the library. If the client works with another server program on the same machine, could it be a timing error being that the Chilkat library is too slow? Any suggestions would be appreciated.